# Excel VBA Find row based on 2 conditions and add to msgbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a log sheet that tracks projects. I'm trying to figure out how to look at each row, find if there is an ID# in column A, if so then check that row to see if there is a date in column H. If the date is missing then a msgbox would popup on open to list all the ID#s that are missing the date.  What I have works when the StrID is defined, but I want to be able to find all the ID#s and list them on a msgbox. Any guidance or a point in the right direction would greatly be appreciated. Thx

```
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strid As String
    Dim strDate As String

    strid = "8"
    strDate = vbNullString

    Set rngFound = Columns("a:a").Find(strid, Cells(Rows.Count, "a:a"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            If LCase(Cells(rngFound.Row, "h:h").Text) = LCase(strDate) Then
                'Found a match
                MsgBox "ID #" & Cells(rngFound.Row, "a:a").Text & "is open."

            End If
            Set rngFound = Columns("a:a").Find(strid, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim msg As String

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To lRow

If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 1).Value) And .Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then

    If .Cells(i, 8).Value = "" Then

        If msg = "" Then

            msg = CStr(.Cells(i, 1).Value)

        Else

            msg = msg + ", " + CStr(.Cells(i, 1).Value)

        End If

    End If

End If

Next i

End With

MsgBox msg

End Sub
```

It loops through each cell in Column A (IDs), and when not blank AND is a number(in case some values are not IDs, but instead text fields), then if the cell in the same row in Column H is blank, add it to `msg`, then show a message box at the end that is `msg`.

Output from my testing is the following:

[image]

Comment: This was perfect and thank you @TheGuyThatDoesn'tKnowMuch!  I was able to add taking the difference in CurrentDate and the dates for each record to show outstanding days next to the IDs in the msgbox as well.